# get the title attribute of the radio buttons that are not checked in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple radio buttons in the form. I wanted to validate those on submit of the page. On submit of the page, if the radio buttons are not checked, I need to display an error message that is given in the title attribute of that radio button. Title is different for different radio buttons.
How can I get the title attribute of that radio button that is not checked?

HTML

```
 <div class="input-container" data-validation="required">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="first" value="First" class="required "title="Please select to continue."/>
<label for="first">First</label>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
$.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function (idx,group) {
        var current = $(group).find('[type=radio]:checked').val();
        alert(current);
        if( current === undefined ) {
            //I need to display the title as the error message
            //like var title = current.attr('title');
            $(group).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
        }


    });
});
});
```

Please find the fiddle of my html

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/15/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: fiddle is empty !!!!!

Comment: i didnt read all, but checkout `:not`

Comment: in a group if no radio is checked then you will have two titles which one you want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/aYipoKE/1/edit)**

```
$('button').click(function(){

   $.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function (idx, el) {
       var current = $(el).find(':radio');
       if( !current.is(':checked') ) {
            var title = current.attr('title');
            $(el).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Roko..Thanks for the solution..Like this can I do for select elements as well?

Comment: @probably, just check for: if select has empty (no) value

Comment: Ok..Will check that..One more query. In the above solution, I need to remove the error message if the user clicks on the radio button. I am trying like this.How can I do that?

Comment: @user1049057 changed also the HTML: http://jsbin.com/aYipoKE/2/edit But look, I don't really understand why programmers are so evil to users... if you really need that radio checked, just make the button disabled until the user selects it.

Comment: Roko..That doesn't seem to be working in my code..Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/23/

Comment: @user1049057 sure it doesn't work cause I've modified the HTML.
If you noticed the label is parent on the input. And I've changed JS accordingly.

Comment: yes..In my html the label is after the parent..So for this $(group).next('ul.innererrormessages').remove(); should work right? but its not working

Comment: @user1049057 Here you go (Note also the new element in HTML) http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/40/

Answer (score 1):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbAyR/)

```
$(function() {
$('button').click(function(){
$.each($('.input-container[data-validation=required]'), function (idx,group) {
        var checked = $(group).find('[type=radio]:checked');
        var unchecked = $(group).find('[type=radio]');

        if(checked.length != unchecked.length ) {
            $.each(unchecked, function(i,v) {
                if($(v).attr('id') != $(checked[i]).attr('id')) {
                    //I need to display the title as the error message
                    var title = $(v).attr('title');
                    $(group).after('<ul class="innererrormessages"><li>'+title+'</li></ul>');    
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```